# Is there a relation between religion and crime rates?

Tags: religion

Each main religion should be listed along with the percantange of their crime rates within the continents of Europe, North America, Asia, and Africa. I'm not asking to merge the continents into crime rate percentages base on religion; the stats can be seperated or catergorize by each continent.

Comment: It is almost impossible to part religion from socio-economic background since it is a property of community, and all communities have such a distinct background influencing things like crime.

Comment: This is an impossible task.  There is no crime rate for a religion, because religions don't commit crimes.  People commit crimes and the person's religion is not normally recorded.

Comment: @JamesK Depends if the religion commands something that is considered a crime? But also that would need to be a minority religion as otherwise the community could make it a law and thus prevent it from being a crime. So yeah pretty hard/impossible task.

Comment: There is another problem with the question, it could be the other way around: Maybe practices of some religions are criminalized more than those of others.

Comment: Would the definition of "religion" for such statistics include things like Marxism and Fascism?

Comment: The original tile sounds opinion based, so I´ve edited it.

Comment: Sure.  https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/daily-quotidien/230322/cg-a004-eng.htm  However, in many of the places the OP references, there is no reason to think that any statistics they might produce are in any way reliable.

Comment: @BobaFit Your data shows hate crimes **targeted at certain religions**, it does not show crimes committed by followers of that religion. It's also limited to hate crimes and those that are religiously motivated. I read OP as looking for general crime rates (regardless of motivation) for followers of certain religions.

Comment: To expand on @JamesK even if the religion is recorded, there is then the question of cultural vs devout followers of a religion. Then the subdivisions of the main religions themselves. The top two, Christianity and Islam, have quite a few sub-variations. We've seen extremist groups from both that appear more prone to criminal activity that the rest of the religion. This question is far too broad with no visible effort put into researching this question beforehand. https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Prison services may record the religion of prisoners for purposes such as providing chaplains or worship. But I'd be skeptical as to whether this corresponds with offending rates in general society before incarceration, due to things like in-prison conversions and the desire for benefits given to worshippers (such as attending services). [Here is some data on US federal prisons](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/are-prisoners-less-likely-to-be-atheists/).